# Last record and first record in separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table as below and need to pull first record in column 2 and last record in column 1&3 based on createDate(column1)

Please help with query

```
column1     column2  column3
CreateDate  Amount   Description 
04/02/2020  36000    First meeting 
04/30/2020  9000     CloseWon
```

Output I need

```
column1     column2  column3
CreateDate  Amount   Description 
04/30/2020  36000     CloseWon
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: What determines the order, `column1`? And why are there two column names/headers, e.g. `column1` and `createdate`? I hope you don't have that name strings in the data.

Answer (score 1):

All supported versions of SQL Server support [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [`LAST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) window functions - so it can be as easy as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(CreateDate) OVER(ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) As CreateDate,
       FIRST_VALUE(Amount) OVER(ORDER BY CreateDate) As Amount,
       FIRST_VALUE(Description) OVER(ORDER BY CreateDate DESC) As Description 
FROM TableName
```

Comment: . . I added the `DISTINCT` so your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [CreateDate] DATE
   ,[Amount] INT
   ,[Description] VARCHAR(18)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([CreateDate], [Amount], [Description])
VALUES ('04/02/2020', 36000, 'First meeting')
      ,('04/30/2020', 9000, 'CloseWon');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [CreateDate] ASC) AS [FirstRow]
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [CreateDate] DESC) AS [LastRow]
          ,*
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT DS2.[CreateDate]
      ,DS1.[Amount]
      ,DS2.[Description]
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[FirstRow] = DS2.[LastRow]
WHERE DS1.[FirstRow] = 1;
```

The idea is to use `ROW_NUMBER` two times - to define the first and the last row. Then, simply result of the common table expression to itself.

If you want to group the data - for example you have another column which is going to defined how records are group:

- add the column(s) to `PARTITION BY` clause of the `ROW_NUMBER`
- when joining the result of the CTE, join by these column(s), too